# firebase getting exact childs from database

Tags: java, android, firebase

i have problem to get exact childs from database and add it to the list of "teams". is that possible? i can't find proper way to solve this problem. please help me.
[image of my actual database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US9f9.png)
i want to get only values of "2" and "3", just list of all teams without members. As a result of my solution im getting all elements from all children.
i have tried sth like this:

```
mDatabase.child("teams").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                teamList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    teamList.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```java
    mDatabase.child("teams").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            teamList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                teamList.add(snapshot.getKey());
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you, i have the same solution to this. thank you again for response

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mDatabase = _firebase.getReference("teams");    
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot _dataSnapshot) {
                    teamList = new ArrayList < > ();
                    try {
                        GenericTypeIndicator < HashMap < String, Object >> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator < HashMap < String, Object >> () {};
                        for (DataSnapshot _data: _dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            HashMap < String, Object > _map = _data.getValue(_ind);
                            teamList.add(_map);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception _e) {
                        _e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError _databaseError) {  }
    });
```